# C# Multiple Download from FTP using parallel task - Duplicate Download issue

Tags: c#, ftp, parallel.foreach

I am facing a strange issue, I want to download a list of files from FTP. I preferred to go with Parallel Task. Below is my code. The issue is, all the list of files are getting downloaded, but duplicate files with different name are being generated. I am very new to Parallel task concept. Please help me to find out the issue.

**Note**: I am using SSH.Net for sftp connection and download.

```
    private void ConcurrentDownload()
    {
        // Declaring Connection Information
        PasswordAuthenticationMethod pm = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("FTPUserName", "Password");
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("FTPHost", 22, "FTPUserName", ProxyTypes.Socks5, "127.0.0.1", 8080, string.Empty, string.Empty, pm);

        using (SftpClient sfc = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
        {
        // Establish the remote connection
        sfc.Connect();

        // Getting Remote Directory Contents
        IEnumerable<SftpFile> sFiles = new List<SftpFile>();    
        sFiles = sfc.ListDirectory(".\\");

        // Building the File List                
        List<string> remotefiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (SftpFile sfile in sFiles)
        {
         if (!sfile.IsDirectory)
         {
           string ss = sfile.Name;
           remotefiles.Add(ss);
         }
        }

        // Parallel Download
        Parallel.ForEach(remotefiles.Distinct(), file => DownloadFile(sfc, file)); 
        sfc.Disconnect();
        }
    }

   private void DownloadFile(SftpClient sf, string RemoteFileName)
   {
        using (Stream ms = File.OpenWrite(RemoteFileName))
        {
            sf.DownloadFile(RemoteFileName, ms);
        }
   }
```

Comment: What's in `remoteFiles`? As it is now, it's an empty collection. Are you sure that you don't have duplicate items in that list when it's populated?

Comment: @xxbbxx remotefiles is a  List<string> and I am very sure, no duplicate filename in it. I am not get duplicate file name, getting duplicate streams in different filenames. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Are SftpClient and DownloadFile thread safe? I couldn't find anything saying that they are. In which case this would account for the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You better use `Distinct` like below

```
Parallel.ForEach(remotefiles.Distinct(), file => DownloadFile(sfc, file));
```

if you have duplicate file names and when parallel processing start on same file you will get exception on those duplicate files.

And also you are not downloading to another location, what you are doing is download to same ftp source location. is that correct?

I would give diferent download directory and get file name from source file and then download to that location as below

```
    private void DownloadFile(SftpClient sf, string RemoteFileName)
    {
        string downloadTo = Path.Combine(DownloadDirectoryPath, Path.GetFileName(RemoteFileName));
        using (Stream ms = File.OpenWrite(downloadTo))
        {
            sf.DownloadFile(RemoteFileName, ms);
        }
    }
```

Related Reference : [SFTP Async Upload in Parallel](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/392482)

Comment: Hi @Damith, remotefiles will not carry duplicate file names. The issue is with the thread I hope. In the Parallel.ForEach, it is downloading wrong stream into different filenames. For Eg: I want to download ABC.XLSX and XYZ.XLSX files from the server (simultaneously). I am getting the output as ABC.XLSX and XYZ.XLSX with same content / sometimes correct content / sometimes interchanged Content.

Comment: remotefiles is a  List<string> and I am very sure, no duplicate filename in it. I am not get duplicate filename, I am getting duplicate streams in different filenames. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: try to create `SftpClient` inside DownloadFile method, don't share the 'SftpClient ' same instant. if `SftpClient` not supporting parallel this way will fail.

Comment: If I create the sftpClient inside the DownloadFile, then it will establish multiple connections with the server where I suppose to establish single connection and download multiple files.

Comment: @ShankarChandrasekaran then there is no point on running in parallel

Comment: can we use thread synchronization in this?, if so what's your advice in it?